# Flutter Navigator.pushNamed() custom route animation

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to use my `CustomPageRoute` in `Navigator.pushNamed()` but I can't find a way to use it.

However, I can use it in following way

```
Navigator.push(context, CustomPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyPage()));
```

This is my route:

```
"/page": (context) => MyPage(), // Can I use CustomPageRoute here, if yes then how?
```

Comment: see `onGenerateRoute` property

Comment: @pskink Thanks, I do know I can achieve it using `onGenerateRoute` but this property is generally used when you don't have static routes and you want to pass some information. In my case I have static route and don't need to pass any info.

Comment: so if you don't want to use it you have to live with the default Route

Comment: @pskink that seems to be the current solution, anyways let's wait if someone might come up with a new idea.

Comment: this is the place where `return widget.onGenerateRoute(settings)` (line 766) has to be used: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/app.dart#L747 - setup a breakpoint in line 748 and debug it step-by-step

Comment: @pskink So that means the only way to proceed is by using `onGenerateRoute`? If yes, then please write it down as answer, I am happy to accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

Recently I ran into the same problem "fixed" it with the `onGeneratePageRoute` hook.

I.e. create a method to dynamically generate the route:

```
  static Route<dynamic> _onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/onboarding':
        return MyCustomPageRoute(builder: (context) => OnboardingScreen(), settings: settings);
    }
    throw UnsupportedError('Unknown route: ${settings.name}');
  }
```

and set it to `onGenerateRoute` in your `MaterialApp`

```
onGenerateRoute: _onGenerateRoute,
```

Looks like you probably already figured this out based on a previous comments but figured I'd make it easier for future people like me who stumble upon this post!

**note:** make sure the route name (in this case `/onboarding`) is not also defined and set to `routes` on your `MaterialApp` as it will only trigger your `onGenerateRoute` if it can't be resolved from your normal routes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package
[page_transition](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition)

and use `onGenerateRoute` in `MaterialApp` and then

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/second':
        return PageTransition(
          child: SecondPage(),
          type: PageTransitionType.scale,
          settings: settings,
        );
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  },
```

make sure to not include the routes whenyou have delcared it in `route:` because it will bypass the onGenerateRoute animation that you want.

For usage, just use like usual `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');`